# Ubuntu VM on Windows 10 Hyper-V can't ping host

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Afternoon Folks,

I've got some very strange behaviour going on with an Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS VM running on Windows 10 Hyper-V. This was working previously, but obviously some update has broken things in a way I can't understand.

Since the last update and reboot, the Ubuntu VM cannot ping the hosts IP address, it just gives me 'Destination Host Unreachable'. The host can ping the VM, and the VM can both ping and be pinged by other machines on the same network with similar IP addresses, on multiple subnets.

So:

- The VM (A.B.C.105) can ping A.B.C.108
- A.B.C.108 can ping the VM
- The host (A.B.C.102) can ping the VM (A.B.C.105)
- The VM (A.B.C.105) reports 'Destination Host Unreachable' when trying to ping the Host (A.B.C.102)

I've tried adding an additional network adapter and saw a similar pattern. The VM just seems to have an issue with the host. I struggling to think what to try next - short of spinning up a new Ubuntu Server instance.

In Hyper-V the VM is using a Bridged switch and can talk to the internet, and other machine on my local network fine.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try with allowing the whole subnet (in which VM and host IP belong) in Windows Firewall in host.

Comment: Thanks @Biswapriyo, but the Windows Firewall is already disabled.